# Finding the Coordinates of a Vector

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hey, I'm confused as to how I would start this problem, and I'm a bit unsure of how to graph a vector? I'm not sure if that would help but do I treat it like regular x,y coordinates? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do treat them like the coordinates. Remember then condition for same slope? Parallelogram has parallel opposite sides.